# Have suggested edits also show the comments to a post

Tags: feature-request, comments, suggested-edits

Some suggested edits like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2726595) at first look like another user trying to hijack a question. Until you see the suggestion's comment stating "Added code snippet provided by OP" - but anyone could claim that, so now you have to open the question in a new tab to check for [referred to provision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18228687/jq-grid-beforecheckvalues-return-type#comment26762895_18228687). I therefore propose that comments are also viewable directly in the edit review view.

Comment: Even more awesome, but much more non-trivial to implement: Add a "edit based on this comment"-option to comments